# Why can't i loop through Outlook.Selection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, com-interop, office-automation

I have a small program which is meant to get the entryId of all the selected email in my mailbox but i for some reason i cant get to the end of the loop without getting an error. The program below is meant to use the OutLookApp.activeExplorer().Selection and return all the Mailitems that are selected, from there I need to loop through the selections and get each EntryId and add them to a comma seperated list, the code some times loop 2 or 4 time but always fail to finish. I dont really understand the error and hoping someone can help.

```
    private string GetEntryID(string ExecutionSource) 
    {
        string TempIDStorage           = null;
        Outlook.Application OutLookApp = _outlookManager.OutlookApplication;
        MailItem OutlookMItem          = null;
        Outlook.Selection _Selection   = null;
        Outlook.Inspector _Inspector   = null;

        if (ExecutionSource == "Main")
        {
            _Selection = OutLookApp.ActiveExplorer().Selection;              
            //Selection = commandContext.Context as Outlook.Selection;
            if (_Selection != null && _Selection.Count > 0)
            {               
                foreach (MailItem items in _Selection) 
                {                      
                    OutlookMItem  = items as Outlook.MailItem; 
                    TempIDStorage = OutlookMItem.EntryID + "," + TempIDStorage;
                }   
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            _Inspector = OutLookApp.ActiveInspector();
            if(_Inspector != null) 
            {
                OutlookMItem = _Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
                TempIDStorage = OutlookMItem.EntryID; 
            }
        }
        return TempIDStorage; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming the selection only contains `MailItem` objects. You can also have `MeetingItem` and `ReportItem` objects:

```cs
foreach (object item in _Selection) 
{                      
    if (item is MailItem mi)
    {
        TempIDStorage = mi.EntryID + "," + TempIDStorage;
    }
}
```

You might also want to consider using `StringBuilder` class instead of the TempIDStorage `string` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook folders contain different types of items - appointments, notes, documents, mail items and etc. You need to check the item type at runtime, for example:

```
Outlook.Explorer currentExplorer = null;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup
    (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    currentExplorer = this.Application.ActiveExplorer();
    currentExplorer.SelectionChange += new Outlook
        .ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler
        (CurrentExplorer_Event);
}

private void CurrentExplorer_Event()
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder selectedFolder =
        this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
    String expMessage = "Your current folder is "
        + selectedFolder.Name + ".\n";
    String itemMessage = "Item is unknown.";
    try
    {
        if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
        {
            Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
            if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is an e-mail message." +
                    " The subject is " + mailItem.Subject + ".";
                mailItem.Display(false);
            }
            else if (selObject is Outlook.ContactItem)
            {
                Outlook.ContactItem contactItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.ContactItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is a contact." +
                    " The full name is " + contactItem.Subject + ".";
                contactItem.Display(false);
            }
            else if (selObject is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            {
                Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.AppointmentItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is an appointment." +
                    " The subject is " + apptItem.Subject + ".";
            }
            else if (selObject is Outlook.TaskItem)
            {
                Outlook.TaskItem taskItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.TaskItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is a task. The body is "
                    + taskItem.Body + ".";
            }
            else if (selObject is Outlook.MeetingItem)
            {
                Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem =
                    (selObject as Outlook.MeetingItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is a meeting item. " +
                     "The subject is " + meetingItem.Subject + ".";
            }
        }
        expMessage = expMessage + itemMessage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        expMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(expMessage);
}
```

See [How to: Programmatically determine the current Outlook item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-outlook-item?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

In your scenario you need to loop over all items in the `Selection` collection using an object:

```
foreach(object item in _Selection) 
{ 
   if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
   {
     Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (item as Outlook.MailItem);
     TempIDStorage = mailItem.EntryID + "," + TempIDStorage;
   }                
}
```

Also if you need to get the property values like `EntryID` you could use the late-binding technology without checking the item type at runtime. That is because all Outlook items provide the `EntryID` property and you can be it exists on every selected item in Outlook. The [Type.InvokeMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.invokemember?view=net-7.0) invokes a specific member of the current `Type`.